# Prolog permutation-code slightly unclear

Tags: prolog, permutation

I just have a little question about the following code I've just written.

```
permu([],[]).
permu([H|T],R) :- same_length([H|T],R), select(H,R,Rz), permu(T,Rz).
```

*Result*: gives out all permutation (doesn't delete redundancies, but that's not the matter; by using `findall` and defining another predicate I can fix that easily)

My initial code:

```
permu([],[]).
permu([H|T],R) :- select(H,R,Rz), permu(T,Rz).
```

*Result*: gives out the first result and ends up in endless loop, when clicking "Next". But when I decided to precisely define their length (with `same_length` as shown above) it suddenly worked.

I have already traced both codes, but I still don't understand why the length of both lists HAS to be defined under any circumstances.
Looking at my initial code, both lists lose one element in each step of the recursion. The list on the left gets its head cut off each run and my `R` variable is being shortened because of `select`. The recursion process ends, when **both** lists run out of elements in the same recursion run => due to `select`, both lists need to share the same number and type of elements.

What does prevent Prolog from realizing it? What makes him fall into the endless loop?

Taking this code as an example I don't have to define the length but it still works:

```
permu([], []).
permu([H|T], R) :- permu(T, Rz), select(H, R, Rz).
```

In contrast to my initial code here the `select` is just put after the recursion call (`permu`).

Comment: In the second implantation, on a query such as `permu([a,b,c], R)`, you have `select(a,R,Rz),`. This is a very broad query with no constraints on the list `R` or `Rz`. So `select` in this case will continue offering solutions for `R` and `Rz` that go unbounded in length. Your 3rd solution bounds the length before you call `select/3`.

Comment: Hello, lurker, and thank you for your quick answer.
Doesn't `select(a,R,Rz)` mean, that the difference between R and Rz is just one element? Why is there no constraint`?

Comment: Yes, that is true. But both `R` and `Rz` are variable. So although the lengths of `Rz` and `R` differ only by 1, that length is unbounded. The difference is bounded to 1, but the overall length is unbounded.

Comment: OHHH, nevermind, I think I got it. So you mean that R and Rz may become bigger and bigger in length so that the endless loop appears?

Comment: Yes that is exactly the problem. At the Prolog prompt, type in `select(a, R, Rz)` and watch what happens.

Comment: Yea, the possible list for R grows into infinity and so does Rz. THANK YOU man, now I understand it. :) Have a nice day!